# Python kivy clock -- how to get intervals to time from the end of the previous iteration?

Tags: python, multithreading, kivy

I'm trying to set up Clock.schedule_interval using Kivy in Python.

The relevant code snippet looks something like this:

```
event = Clock.schedule_interval(lambda x: refresh(),20)
```

The `refresh` function usually takes approx 10 seconds to run, but occasionally it will take 60 seconds.

I want the 20 second wait to occur *between* each iteration of refresh.

That is, I'd like it to work like this:

1. Refresh. Wait for it to complete (approx 10-60 seconds).
2. After completion, wait 20 seconds.
3. Refresh again. Etc.

It seems like the default behavior is to start the 20 second timer when refresh *starts*, not when it *completes*. Is there a way to change this?

Also, if refresh is taking 60s and the 20s interval passes, will it start refresh a second time even though refresh is ongoing? Will it queue another thread? If so, is there a way to tell it "If refresh hasn't completed yet, skip this iteration and wait another interval"?

Thanks for any help you can offer!

Answer (score 1):

Use Clock.schedule_once() to run refresh() the first time, then add a Clock.schedule_once() at the end of the refresh() method to schedule itself again in 20 sec.